# Do we really have 1.7k late answers to review?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reviewing

Just seen this on the Arqade Review page:

[image: 1.7k Late Answers]

Do we really have 1.7k late answers to review? I skipped through a couple and the answers do seem to be queued.

Is that a bug? Or what is it?

Comment: [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue/267080#267080) explains why there is a sudden influx of things to review here.

Comment: In 3 hours we've cleared ~600 of them!

Comment: It's been twice now that I've hit my review limit for late answers.

Comment: Now how many we'll have once the bar is raised too 100 rep... at least I might be able to get a gold badge faster for that queue.

Comment: A question about the number 1.7k that gets 17 votes, with its only answer having 17 votes as well. What a time to be alive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, it's not a bug.** Upon accessing the review queue, answers dating all the way back to a few years ago can be seen, as the reputation thresholds for Late Answers have been changed. Answers are now eligible to go into the queue if the person answering has any less than 50 reputation earned on the site rather than just 1 reputation.

It <strike>may well have been</strike> *is definitely* something caused by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue/267080#267080) Meta.SE suggestion being put into place.

[Another meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267081/why-did-the-late-answer-queue-spike-on-sep-29-2015) also shows that this isn't exclusive to Arqade, and is in fact widespread across each SE site.

Comment: They weren't reviewed because the thresholds changed.

Comment: @AshleyNunn That's another thing to add, give me a moment.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the same happened to the EE.SE queue. Well, let's get to work :D

Comment: @AshleyNunn We have 40 reviews but at that speed, how fast we're gonna burn 1.5k reviews (at the time of this comment)? Any ways to get more review per person for a limited time?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I don't think that's necessary. The number dropped by over 100 in just 10 minutes. By tomorrow they will probably all be dealt with.

Comment: And we've smashed through the list! Nice work everyone! :)